# Bulk update of column values of entire table

Tags: oracle11g

We have an Oracle 11g database table with around 35 million rows. We are in a situation where we have to update all values of one column. This column is indexed.

I have a script that can generate the updated values and can populate it in a text file.

I'm looking for a good strategy to do a bulk update to this table. We can afford a downtime of around 10 hours.

Will it be a good idea to

- Dump the entire table to a flat file
- Update the values using any scripting language
- Reload the entire table
- Rebuild indexes

What are the pitfalls that one can encounter?

I'm not competent in PL/SQL. Is there a way to solve this in PL/SQL or any way "within" the database itself?

Thanks,
Prabhu

Comment: Edit: the column is indexed. Corrected that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way will probably be to create an [external table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/tablecls.htm#sthref81) based on your flat file of update values and then:

```
create table new_table as
  select o.col1, o.col2, o.col3, ..., x.value as colN
  from old_table o
  join extern_table x on ...;
```

(Make sure that join returns all the rows from old_table.  The join may need to be an outer join.)

```
-- drop foreign key constraints that reference old_table
alter table child1 drop constraint fk_to_old_table1;
...

drop table old_table;

rename new_table to old_table;

-- Re-create indexes and constraints on old_table
alter table old_table add constraint oldpk primary key (col1);
...

-- Re-create the dropped foreign key constraints to old_table
alter table child1 add constraint fk_to_old_table1 ...;
...
```

Comment: Tony, Thanks for your response. I cannot provide the updated value in the query itself, as I need to run an external script to generate the updated value. That will be in a text file.

Comment: I have updated my answer: you can use an external table to join your flat file into the query to create the new table.